# How to get diagonal of a bounding box?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm facing a simple problem but I don't know how to solve it!

I would like to get the diagonal of a boundingbox. I'm working on a Leaflet map and I have to get the diagonal of the current grip (`emprise` in French).

I'm able to get the current bounding box but I don't know to calculate the diagonal of this.

I know that the diagonal of a rectangle is `diagonal = \sqrt(side1^2 + side2^2)`. But I don't know how to do this with coordinates (of my bounding box).

Comment: Lat/Lon Bounds or Cartesian (pixel) Bounds?

Comment: Leaflet provides lat/lng bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet supports both pixel based bounding boxes through [Bound](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#bounds) and Geo Coordinate bounding boxes through [LatLonBounds](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#latlngbounds)

Use the [`Point.distanceTo(OtherPoint)`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#latlng-distanceto) method:

`p1.distanceTo(p2);`